# Showing images next to paragraph

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align an image to the right of a paragraph. That's all working perfectly but the problem is I want it "responsive", because sometimes there aren't any images at all so then I want the text to fill the white area. Another note is that it's always different on how many images there are. It's hard to explain but I hope you understand it.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kS4eBak8vtQN9oklb8Ay?p=preview) so you can try something. In the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kS4eBak8vtQN9oklb8Ay?p=preview) it works perfectly but not if the next slide has no images then there is a big white area.

HTML code:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="slideHeader">
      <img align="left" style="padding-right: 20px;" src="https://cdn3.colorlib.com/dazzling/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2013/03/image-alignment-150x150.jpg">
      <h1 style="padding-left: 20px;">Hello world!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slideContent">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="slideImages">
      <div>
        <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slideHeader {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}

.slideContent {
  top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  background-color: white;
}

.slideImages {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  right: 25px;
}
```

Example of how I want it to look when there are images:

[image: Example]

Example of how I want it to look when there are no images:

[image: Example]

(All the way to the right, no white space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of using `position: absolute;` every time.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uwpLm1ah/)**

Below is updated code:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div class="slideHeader">
      <img align="left" style="padding-right: 20px;" src="https://cdn3.colorlib.com/dazzling/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2013/03/image-alignment-150x150.jpg">
      <h1 style="padding-left: 20px;">Hello world!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slideImages">
      <div>
        <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideContent">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
      sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
      Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.
    </div>

  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slideHeader {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
.slideContent {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.slideImages {
  float:right;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: You are most wellcome

Comment: One note: I got white space at the top of the page now? [image](https://i.gyazo.com/12f472508714619a8ef2411f9cc42c9d.png)

Comment: use * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} and remove all top values

Answer (score 0):

Use float instead of absolute positioning if you want content to wrap around each other.

```
.slideContent {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideImages {
  float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2gg2e7e8/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not working for me. I removed the `<img>` and it showed me a white area.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to remove the 150px padding. Anyway Arun's solution is what I was trying to do, and it's more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use this code below:

```
if ($('.slideImages').lenght) {
  // code here if slideimage have          
    }
    else {
   // code here if slideimage don't have          
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you help and even though it will work, I prefer without Jquery.